# .NET Standard Nuget References

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-4.7

I am making a class library in .NET Standard, which I wish to be usable from Windows and Android. However, when I try to reference the project or the project output directly, then I get `AssemblyNotFoundException`s at runtime, with a different one for each NuGet package that my .NET Standard project references. Adding each NuGet package to every project that references the .NET Standard project makes this problem go away, but it feels like an unsustainable solution. **What is the best way to resolve the dependencies in a .NET Standard project?** I am using Visual Studio 2017, my console project is .NET 4.7, and my .NET Standard project is .NET Standard 1.6.

I have already referenced NETStandard.Library from my console project, but it does not work. Type such as System.ValueTuple still throw exceptions when I attempt to use them.

Right now, the exception I am getting upon attempting to run my program is this:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Which makes sense, as I use serialization in my .NET Standard library.

Comment: There can be a need to add necessary assembly redirection in your app.config file. Post the exact exception you got please.

Comment: @LexLi `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
`

Comment: the actual assembly in your bin folder might be 4.3.0.0. Check that and learn how to redirect.

Comment: Are you referencing the output dll directory or do you use a project reference?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have tried both, and neither work.

Comment: Can you reproduce it using a new netstandard library + console app or does it just fail on Xamarin? Does the resulting .exe.config contain binding redirects?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I was never using Xamarin, I am indeed already using a netstandard library and a console app. For now, I have simply resorted to installing all the NuGet packages on both projects, but I will try uninstalling them and checking the exe.config later.

Comment: @333 can you check if the answer of this helps you? (force msbuild to generate binding redirects): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995432/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-abstrac/43996389#43996389

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use .Net Standard 1.4 for your referenced library?