# Cannot load System.ComponentModel.Annotations from OrmLiteConfigExtensions (ServiceStack.OrmLite.Core)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I get a runtime error when using `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Core` package (5.4.1) and trying to get a `ModelDefinition` (`ServiceStack.OrmLite.ModelDefinition`) by doing:

```
var model = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition;
```

The error reads as follows:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

I have tried to install nuget System.ComponentModel.Annotations (4.5.0.0 since 4.2.0.0 isnt available) to no avail. 
I have also tried [various fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053187/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-componentmodel-annotations-version-4-1) suggested when encountering System.IO.FileLoadException, but nothing works.

The project is a .Net Framework 4.7.1 project but .Net Standard projects are included in the solution so I need to run the .Core version of ServiceStack.OrmLite.

I have tried this on two workspaces (two separate machines), (1) as described above, and (2) where no .Net Standard projects are in the solution.
On the (2) machine it works when running the non Core version of `ServiceStack.OrmLite`, but switching to `ServiceStack.OrmLite.Core` the runtime error occurs.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually I figured it out…

As It turns out `ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql.Core` requires `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` version 4.2.0.0 as the error message clearly states. Normally it works to install a version equal to or greater than what’s required but in this case none of that worked. And for some reason it seems as the latest release included in FX is 4.0.0.0 (or at least that’s what I get when I include the assembly version of it.) There is also a nuget installing version 4.5.0.0, but the outcome is the same.

I have no idea why it works out of the box using the FX versions of `ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql`, but when using the Core version as I do, I find no way of avoiding this without the following fix:

In my startup project, I need to add an assembly binding telling `ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql.Core` that `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` version 4.2.0.0 “redirects” to 4.0.0.0 (of the same assembly). It looks like this:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
     </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
```

I'm sure there are people out there who can explain the details around this, me not one of them but nonetheless… adding this to the startup projects app.config will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to repro this I've resolved a different issue with the [ASP.NET Core Apps on the .NET Framework templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) referencing the latest [v5.4.1 MyGet packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) where the **Tests .csproj** should be referencing the new `ServiceStack.Kestrel.Core` package instead of `ServiceStack.Kestrel`, i,e:

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Kestrel.Core" Version="5.*" />
```

Which is now updated in all `.Core` templates. To access the latest v5.4.1 packages on MyGet you'd need to clear your NuGet packages cache:

```
$ nuget locals all -clear
```

Then install latest [web-corefix](https://github.com/NetFrameworkCoreTemplates/web-corefx) project using the new `web` .NET Core tool:

```
$ dotnet tool install --global web

$ web new web-corefx WebCoreFx
```

I've then added a reference to OrmLite MySql in `WebCoreFx.csproj`:

```
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql.Core" Version="5.*" />
```

And updated [Startup.cs](https://github.com/NetFrameworkCoreTemplates/web-corefx/blob/master/MyApp/Startup.cs) to register the MySql provider, create and select from a table simple table and access its `ModelDefinition<T>.Definition` API:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig {
        DefaultRedirectPath = "/metadata",
        DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false)
    });

    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
        "Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=root;Password=test;SslMode=none",
        MySqlDialect.Provider));

    using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().OpenDbConnection())
    {
        db.DropAndCreateTable<Person>();

        db.Insert(new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Name"});

        var s = db.Select<Person>().Dump();
        s.PrintDump();
    }

    var model = ModelDefinition<Person>.Definition;
    model.Name.Print();
}
```

Which works as expected and runs without issue.

If you still have issues can you upload a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub I can run locally to repro the issue.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt follow that. 
Clear cache, and update from nuget (same version), so far so good. 
But web-corefx? Im not sure how it relates to my project or why I need it? 
Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ErikLindberg you’re trying to run ASP.NET Core on .NET FX right? The web-corefx creates an empty project with the correct package references after which adding OrmLite.MySql lets me use OrmLite and access ModelDefinition<T> without issue. I’m unable to repro your exact issue with the info provided so hopefully it’s just a matter of starting from a new project with a working configuration, if not upload you can upload your project to GitHub and I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and others related to SqlClient not supported. Make sure the regular .net app is set to use PackageReference instead of packages.config. If not migrate it. This solved my issues without having to put in a bunch of binding redirects.