# Library trying to load wrong version of assembly

Tags: c#, dependencies, version, .net-standard

I have a .NET Standard project that uses the library "RethinkDb.Driver" but when I start my project and I have the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies
```

However, my project already uses Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3.
I however can't go back to the version 10.0.0 because I'm also using another library that needs the latest version.
I checked my .csproj and the PackageReference is here, pointing to the version 12.0.3
I also already tried things like cleaning the NuGet cache but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: There are plenty solutions for this using `<bindingRedirect/>`

Comment: Check this question, looks like possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053187/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-componentmodel-annotations-version-4-1?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `assembly redirect`.

You have to put it in your config file.
It will be `app.config` in library and executable project, and `web.config` if it's a web project

That is a directive to dotnet to resolve this dependency to `newVersion`

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.3.0" newVersion="12.0.3.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: When doing that I have the same error, but now with the version 12.0.3.0

Comment: Try to put 12.0.0.0 in new version

Comment: May I also ask you why you are putting 0.0.0.0-12.0.3.0 in "oldVersion", since the that RethinDb.Driver is trying to use is 10.0.0.0?

Comment: That is on the safe side. To be sure all version will point only to a single version