# LinqPad -Getting Error: "Could not load file or assembly "System.ComplonentModel.Annotations Version 4.2.0.0 ...." when trying to connect to DLL

Tags: linqpad, linqpad5

When I use "Use typed data context from your own assembly" to connect to my dll I get this error "Could not load file or assembly "System.ComplonentModel.Annotations Version 4.2.0.0 ...."

Details Steps:

1. Select "Use typed data context from your own assembly"
2. SelectEntity Framework DbContext (v4,v5, v6)
3. Error Pops up: Could not load file or assembly "System.ComplonentModel.Annotations Version 4.2.0.0 ...."

I am using

- LinkPAD : v5.47.0 (Premium Version)
- Enity Framework: 6.4.4
- .Net Framework: 4.8.4084.0

Any Help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: click F4 - check your using and check nuget packages

Comment: answer could be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053187/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-componentmodel-annotations-version-4-1 (But nog enough experience to be sure ... )