# Azure function startup errors

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have a working Azure Function which is recently updated to .NET Framework 4.7 however i am running it with .NET Standard SDK as it cannot yet go fully core. However on startup i continue to get this error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have no idea really what is causing this. This nuget is also not directly used in my function and there are no traces.

What could be causing this.

I am using Microsoft.ASP.NET.Core 2.1.6 version

Comment: This is answer maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995432/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-abstrac