# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've recently updated to the latest .net core 3.0 SDK, updated all my nugets to also include pre-release versions, however I keep getting this error come up when I try to do anything with Pomeolo / Entity Framework with MySQL.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. An operation is not legal in the current state. (0x80131509)
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: AssemblyLoadContext is unloading or was already unloaded.
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.VerifyIsAlive()
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)
   at AltV.Net.Host.ResourceAssemblyLoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NamedConnectionStringResolverBase.ResolveConnectionString(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection..ctor(RelationalConnectionDependencies dependencies)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

I have tried stable and pre-release versions, I have this file also included in Nuget and it's version is 2.2.0.0. This seems to be an issue with .Net Core 3.0 or Pomelo?

My code:

```
try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Before Context");
                using Context context = new Context();
                Console.WriteLine("After Context");
                List<Models.Vehicle> vehicles = context.Vehicle.Where(x => x.Spawned).ToList();

                Console.WriteLine($"Resetting {vehicles.Count} Vehicle Spawn Status");

                foreach (Models.Vehicle vehicle in vehicles)
                {
                    vehicle.Spawned = false;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Completed resetting vehicle spawn statuses");
                context.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

I am getting to this line:

```
 Console.WriteLine("After Context");
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up binding redirects? REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43996389/390122

Comment: Yeah I have. I think it's to do with Pomelo not being updated.

Comment: Pretty mysterious mishap.  A somewhat similar case is [reported here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26367) but that one makes a lot more sense than this one.  You'd better file your own bug report.

Comment: how u fix ths? having this issue with. net 6

Answer (score 0):

You must use exactly the same .NET Core, ASP.NET Core, and EF Core preview version.
Make sure all packages from [dotnet](https://github.com/dotnet) or [aspnet](https://github.com/aspnet) are `rc1` as for now.
If some dependencies (including direct and indirect) in your project depend on any 2.2 packages that are from [dotnet](https://github.com/dotnet) or [aspnet](https://github.com/aspnet) and has a 3.0 new version, reference them as 3.0 rc1 version from your own project explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for a .NET Core 3 compatible version of the Pomelo provider.