# Use Entity Framework Core 3.0 in .Net 4.7.2 Web Forms application

Tags: asp.net, web, webforms, entity-framework-core

I was hoping to be able to create a EF core 3.0 DAL project and use this for my database operation in a .Net 4.7.2 Web forms application. But it looks like the latest EF core 3.0 targets .Net Standard 2.1 and .Net 4.7.2 is not compatible with that? Is there any way to make use of EF Core 3.0 and DI with a Web forms app or do I just need to use EF6?

Comment: You need EF Core 3.1 to target .NET Framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need help installing EFCore 3.0 on .net framework 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175964/i-need-help-installing-efcore-3-0-on-net-framework-4-8)

Comment: Yes upgrading to EF Core 3.1 has helped although to use the command line tools to generate my models I have to create a .Net core console app that references my class library DAL project. When only referencing my DAL project from the .Net 4.7.2 web form project I got an error when generating the models saying no target framework could be found.

Comment: Entity Framework 6.3 supports both .NET frameworks you mention.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef-core-3-0-and-ef-6-3-general-availability/#what-s-new-in-ef-6-3